# Linq Order by a specific number first then show all rest in order

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting

If i have a list of numbers:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

and I want to order by a specific number and then show the rest.
For example if i pick '3' the list should be:

```
3,1,2,4,5,6,7,8
```

Looking for linq and c#.
Thank you

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can use a comparison in `OrderBy` or `ThenBy` to perform a conditional sorting.

```
list.OrderByDescending(i => i == 3).ThenBy(i => i);
```

I use `OrderByDescending` because i want matching results first(`true` is "higher" than `false`).

Comment: @cracker: change `OrderByDescending` to `OrderBy` or `i == 3` to `i != 3`

Comment: if want to sort string column `myDataList.OrderByDescending(i => i.StringColumnValue[0] == filterStringValue[0]).ToList()`  . i used your logic here. Based on filter starting letter, those results are displayed in the order with same starting letter

Comment: So integer collection works but object collection is not working, am i missing anything here ?
object.OrderByDescending(m => m.id== 298).ThenBy(x => x.CreatedOn)

Comment: @ManishJoisar: it works the same way. The point is that `m.id== 298` returns a `bool` which can be `true` or `false` and `OrderByDescending` will yield the `true`-values first. Maybe the reason why you think that it doesn't work is somethingelse. Create a question, so others can help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213940/orderbydescending-specific-data-1st-and-then-rest-in-order

Answer (score 8):

A couple of answers already sort the last few numbers (which may be correct since you're only showing an already sorted list). If you want the "unselected" numbers to be displayed in their *original, not necessarily sorted order* instead of sorted, you can instead do;

```
int num = 3;
var result = list.Where(x => x == num).Concat(list.Where(x => x != num));
```

As @DuaneTheriot points out, [IEnumerable's extension method OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) does a stable sort and won't change the order of elements that have an equal key. In other words;

```
var result = list.OrderBy(x => x != 3);
```

works just as well to sort 3 first and keep the order of all other elements.

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing with `list.OrderBy(i => i != 3)`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this:

```
List<int> ls=new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int nbr=3;
var result= ls.OrderBy (l =>(l==nbr?int.MinValue:l));
```

Comment: Sorry for the necro comment, but this isn't a good idea.  Because if the list contains any entries of int.MinValue, this approach isn't going to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeAndOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> f)
{       
    foreach ( var item in items.Where(f))
        yield return item;
    foreach (var item in items.Where(i=>!f(i)).OrderBy(i=>i))
        yield return item;
}


var items = new [] {1, 4, 2, 5, 3};
items.TakeAndOrder(i=> i == 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code with list of dynamic string values

```
var defaultSortingInternalTrades = ["E,F,G"];
    
var ItemsToSort = ["A","B","C","D","E",...];
var fData = items.Where(d => defaultSortingInternalTrades.Contains(d.ToString()))
                 .OrderBy(x => defaultSortingInternalTrades.IndexOf(x.ToString())).ToList();
var oData = items.Where(d => !defaultSortingInternalTrades.Contains(d.ToString())).ToList();
fData.AddRange(oData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @joachim-isaksson idea I came up with this extension method:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderByWithGivenValueFirst<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    TKey value
    ) 
    => source.OrderBy(x => !keySelector(x).Equals(value));
```

Test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class when_ordering_by_with_given_value_first
{
    [Test]
    public void given_value_is_first_in_the_collection()
    {
        var languages = new TestRecord[] {new("cs-CZ"), new("en-US"), new("de-DE"), new("sk-SK")};

        languages.OrderByWithGivenValueFirst(x => x.Language, "en-US")
            .ShouldBe(new TestRecord[] {new("en-US"), new("cs-CZ"), new("de-DE"), new("sk-SK")});

    }

    private record TestRecord(string Language);
}
```