# OrderByDescending - specific data 1st and then rest in order

Tags: c#, sorting

We have data as follows

| Created On | Supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Nov-21 | ABC |
| 02-Nov-21 | XYZ |
| 15-Nov-21 | ABC |
| 20-Nov-21 | MNO |
| 25-Nov-21 | ABC |

So we want to record in descending order of creation but 1st want all "ABC" records on the top.

I tried with this one, but didn't worked.

```
object.OrderByDescending(m => m.name== "ABC").ThenBy(x => x.CreatedOn)
```

So instead of getting records as follows

```
01-Nov-21   |   ABC  
15-Nov-21   |   ABC
25-Nov-21   |   ABC  
02-Nov-21   |   XYZ  
20-Nov-21   |   MNO
```

It was coming in same order as above i.e. based on createdOn field

Am i missing anything here?

Comment: You have to explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: did you reassign the result? `object = object.OrderByDescending()`

Comment: .OrderByDescending() expects a property not an expression, no?

Comment: @gkb: No, it expects something that returns a value which is the key for the sorting. In this case a `bool`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter
Question updated

Comment: [It works OK for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPLlVH).

Comment: **Guess:** It may happen, that `Supplier` has *trailing spaces*, *invisible characters* etc. That's why `m => m.name == "ABC"` is always `false`. Could you, please, try 
`.OrderByDescending(m => m.name.Contains("ABC")).ThenBy(x => x.CreatedOn)`? Or even `.OrderByDescending(m => m.name.Contains("A")).ThenBy(x => x.CreatedOn)`

Comment: The sorting itself works as expected. But in it doesnt work inplace (as it does for instance in javascript), thus it doesn't modify the original collection but returns a new collection which you will have to assign to a variable

Comment: Does the `name` property correspond to the `Supplier` column in the data table?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko was right, issue was related to trailing space/invisible characters.  So it is working as expected. Thanks all for your help to analyze this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in descending order of creation but 1st want all "ABC" records on the top

You need to use `ThenByDescending` - using `OrderByDescending` initially doesn't then set the sorting of the date up to be descending too

I don't personally think you should sort a bool in your first clause, because it's not obvious to everyone how booleans sort. Rather than it be something one has to remember/look up, I would recommend that you use the bool to generate an int for sorting because everyone can easily understand your intent (everyone can put 0 and 1 into ascending order):

```
foreach(var x in list.OrderBy(m => m.name == "ABC" ? 0 : 1).ThenByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn))
  //process your objects in turn here
```

To achieve a "date descending but all ABC on top" you first sort on whether something is ABC or not (and bear in mind that that's an exact, case sensitive match, unless this query is being translated to SQL and send to a DB like SQL server, where case sensitivity depends on the collation of the column being sorted/where trailing spaces may be ignored), then you want to sort the date *descending* with `ThenByDescending`.

Comment: Haven't downvoted, but this will certainly not help OP to solve his issue because it's the same result. One might find this more or less readable though. A `true` is "higher" than `false`, that's why OP's approach [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933943/284240).

Comment: This is an opinion and should be a comment. It does not answer the question.

Comment: One *can* sort by `bool`: the order is `false < true`:  `public struct Boolean : IComparable, IConvertible, IComparable<Boolean>,  IEquatable<Boolean>`
 https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,f1b135ff6c380b37

Comment: Yes, but my point is that it's not very *glanceable* - ask any human to "put 0 and 1 in descending order" and they'll be able to do it off the bat.. "put true and false in descending order" will probably elicit a "whut?"

Comment: @CaiusJard So the reason that OPs code does not work is because it isn't readable?

Comment: We don't know why the OP's code doesn't work, because they haven't defined "doesn't work", however the code in the answer given meets the sorting requirements specification given in the question

Comment: @CaiusJard It might (not even sure about that) be more readable to sort by `0` and `1` instead of `false` and `true`. But that won't solve OP's problem. Because the sort is working as expected. But as we don't know how the result is used, the cause of the problem is unknown. Also OP's code meets the sorting requirements. The problem problably lies in how the result is used

Comment: *Also OP's code meets the sorting requirements* - disagree; op said they want date descending, but given code does `ThenBy` which is ascending

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the descending date, missed that in the question. But it meets the requirement of sorting `ABC` first ...

Comment: Furthermore what OP posts as text (ie wants created on descending) and what he posted as example desired result (ie created on ascending) contradict each other ...

Comment: That info was added after the answer was posted. To avoid getting into a constant goalpost shifting where every worsening iteration of a question requires more updates/guesses, I plan to wait until the OP responds to the answer with either "yes, it worked for me" or "no, it did not" at which point I'm happy to engage with them further to sound out how. They seem to have wandered off at the moment