# Ordering Linq list by array elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, .net-core

I have below code -

```
var refNosToOrder = new int[9] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

var orderedList = lst.OrderBy(x=>x.RefNo==7)
                     .ThenBy(y=> refNosToOrder.Contains(y.RefNo)).ToList();
```

`lst` is list of class object containing int property - RefNo : i.e. `List<SampleClass>`

```
class SampleClass
{
  public int RefNo {get;set;}
}
```

`lst` contains all the unsorted data of `RefNo`:

```
lst = 2,4,6,9,7,5,8,1,3
```

What I want to do -

First I want to order `lst` by keeping first element as - `7`; then for the rest of the list, it should be ordered as the array `refNosToOrder`

i.e. Final output I am expecting to be -

```
7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9
```

With the above code -

```
var orderedList = lst.OrderBy(x=>x.RefNo==7)
                         .ThenBy(y=> refNosToOrder.Contains(y.RefNo)).ToList();
```

It is giving - `2,4,6,9,7,5,8,1,3` i.e. this code is not at all ordering the list.

Comment: Shouldn't your `ThenBy()` contain somethin like `ThenBy(y => y.RefNo)` ? Look at [this post where I saw that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933888/linq-order-by-a-specific-number-first-then-show-all-rest-in-order/9933943)

Comment: No .. Rest of the RefNo should get ordered by refNosToOrder array @Error404Brainnotfound

Comment: Oh my bad, i didn't understand that part of the question!

Comment: So what if `refNosToOrder` is `6, 6, 6, 6`? Would you want four copies of the original? Is `refNosToOrder` always going to be (effectively) a number followed by a linear sequence that doesn't have that number?

Comment: refNosToOrder will always have unique elements in it. I dont want to have copies. @JeroenMostert

Comment: OK, but how are you building `refNosToOrder`? I ask because a solution where you order elements by `refNosToOrder` can certainly be written (just make it `refNosToOrder.Select(...)` and look up the elements from `lst`, not the other way around) but your ordering logic may actually be much simpler and not require a separate, explicit array of numbers that could order the elements any which way. You cannot, in any case, use `OrderBy` here unless you join the two lists first, but that sounds more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Contains` returns a boolean of whether an element is in a list or not, which won't be very helpful here. Instead, you could sort by the index of that element:

```cs
var orderedList = 
    lst.OrderBy(x => x.RefNo != 7)
       .ThenBy(y => Array.IndexOf(refNosToOrder, y.RefNo))
       .ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
Following up on Jeroen Mostert's comment, this sorting has quadratic complexity. For large `refNosToOrder` it may be more efficient to first convert the array to a dictionary of orders and then use it for the sorting:

```cs
var orderDict = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, refNosToOrder.Length).ToDictionary(i => refNosToOrder[i]);
var orderedList = 
    lst.OrderBy(x => x.RefNo != 7).ThenBy(y => orderDict[y.RefNo]).ToList();
```

Comment: Do note that this solution has quadratic performance due to the repeated linear search in `refNosToOrder` -- OK if your arrays are 10 elements, no longer OK if they're 10 000 elements. At that point creating lookups first starts to make sense.

Comment: @JeroenMostert good point, thanks! Edited that in to the answer (with the appropriate credit, of course)

Comment: @Mureinik - If lst contains elements outside the refNosToOrder - then it is giving preference to those numbers after 7. Eg. if lst contains - 2,4,6,9,7,5,8,1,3 and refNosToOrder = 3,4,5 then it is outputing as - 7,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9 ; where it should have been - 7,3,4,5,1,2,6,8,9